# Problems splitting text into sentences

Tags: stanford-nlp, text-processing

I am trying to find the best approach to split text into sentences.

I tried Stanford NLP and I was actually disappointed how badly it performed.

For instance

```
"Who are you?" asked another man.
```

It recognized as two sentences: `"Who are you?"` and `asked another man`.

```
He said, "Nothing. Nothing at all."
```

It recognized as two sentences:

`He said, "Nothing.` and `Nothing at all."`.

I also tried plain vanilla Java BreakIterator.getSentenceInstance and it does not understand any abbreviations. For instance Mr. President it splits into two sentences "Mr." and "President". Stanford NLP though did not split Samuel L. Jackson or George W. Bush into multiple sentences.

So I am at loss on what else to try.

Comment: You might be trying edge cases. How does your target text perform?

Comment: I an not trying edge cases. This is normal text.

Comment: I mean edge cases for the model. It might have been trained on different texts. Do you have specific texts to split? If so can you show an example?

Comment: I use Stanford NLP library. This is sample text I tried:

"Dead." He said it without emotion.

He said, "Nothing. Nothing at all."

Finally he said, "Certainly a complication... but not a problem. 

He stared at Court for a long time. "A familiar face," he said. "Without the beard and the rainwater, perhaps I would know you?"

"Who are you?" asked another man.

Court didn't answer. Instead he said, "We need to go inside. Quickly."

The outcome of the negotiations is vital, because the current tax levels signed into law by President George W. Bush expire on Dec. 31.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main methodologies to do sentence splitting:

1. Rule based model
2. Predictive model

CoreNLP uses the class TokenizeProcessor for sentence splitting and tokenization

The Stanford NLP package used the data to train their English model using http://universaldependencies.org

It seems the quote character `"` is an  important feature in your data.

Reviewing one of the test data sets, there are only 36 instances out of 2000 sentences.

If this is indicative, it seems the sentence splitting model doesn't represent that feature well, meaning it will probably not work well on splitting sentences with quotes.

This is quite common, and most likely you will have to train the sentence splitting model for your data.

Alternatively, a rule based approach might work if the context of your data is reliable.